# Calling to python interactive script from another script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7
I have interactive Python script, named A, written using Cmd module.
However, sometimes there is a need to activate script A from other Python scripts.
It also could be nice if the interactive script A wouldn't exit in between commands given to them.
I tried to search for solutions and I found  couple [here](https://pymotw.com/2/cmd/)

One is to pass a file from which the interactive script will read commands. It works well for me but it is not much liked.
Another is to use echo which doesn't work for me (still trying).

I wonder whether there are other solutions.....

Comment: you can use os.system() to interact with the command line and then call the script from your current file . __If possible show us what you have till now i.e code__

Comment: @babygame0ver I don't think my code will add any input in this case. It is  a classic usage of Cmd module. When the script A is activated it expects commands to be given to it. It is comfortable for human users but tricky for activation from other scripts. I will look into os.system() to see how I can use it for my purposes. Thanks

Comment: __if you will show us some code that will be useful__